# How can i add fields in my CustomUserCreationForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-users

**Forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    #phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email','first_name','last_name', 'phone_number', 'middle_name')
```

**Admin.py**

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    fieldsets = (
        (('User'), {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name',
         'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_parent', 'is_teacher')}),
    )
```

**Models.py** (*All the fields in **Admin.py** are declared here without errors*)

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
```

[AddNewUser Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HBI6.png)

As you can see, I tried adding a Charfield directly in CustomUserCreationForm and I also tried adding fields but it just would not appear whenever I add new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    fieldsets = (
        (('None'), {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name',
         'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_parent', 'is_teacher')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name',
         'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_parent', 'is_teacher' ),
        }),
    )
    admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin),
```

Comment: glad that it helped :)